# How to insert data in mysql database using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, mysql-workbench

```
string query2 = "INSERT INTO library_database.status_of_issue VALUES('";
query2 = query2 +textBox2.Text + "','";
query2 = query2 + textBox1.Text + "', CURDATE(),ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(query2, con);
MySqlDataReader d1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
MessageBox.Show("Issed...");
d1.Close();
```

Comment: The error comes that there is an error in sql syntax.

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing the closing parenthesys for the VALUES clause, but your query should be rewritten to avoid [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and an INSERT query is executed with `ExecuteNonQuery`

```
string query2 = @"INSERT INTO library_database.status_of_issue VALUES(@p1, @p2,
                  CURDATE(),ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY))";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(query2, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", textBox1.Text);
int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(rows > 0)
     MessageBox.Show("insert OK...");
```

Answer (score 0):

So very obvious. You're missing the ending paranthesis of VALUES. This should work:

```
string query2 = string.Format("INSERT INTO library_database.status_of_issue VALUES('{0}', '{1}', CURDATE(), ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY))", textBox2.Text, textBox1.Text);

using(var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query2, con))
{
    if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Issed...");
}
```

Also note that INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands should be executed using `ExecuteNonQuery()`.